# How can I read all files in the same directory?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I made a code for counting words in a file.

But I want to adjust it to read all `.txt` files in the same directory. I found that I have to use `<filesystem>` but I dont know how to adjust it.

```
int EBook::get_total_num_words() 
{
    map <string, int> words;
    int count = 0;
    string ws;
    ifstream file("inputs\\test.txt");
    std::string path = "\\inputs";
    //for (const auto& entry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(path)) {
    while (file >> ws) {
        if (words[ws])
        {
            ++words[ws];
            

        }
        else {
            words[ws] = 1;
            
        }
    }
    file.close();
    return (int)words.size();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know about `directory_iterator`. Simply move the `ifstream` inside the loop, constructing it with the `path` of the current `entry`, eg:

```
int EBook::get_total_num_words() 
{
    map <string, int> words;
    string word;
    
    std::string path = "\\inputs";
    for (const auto& entry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(path)) {
        if (entry.path().extension().string() != ".txt") continue;
        ifstream file(entry.path());
        while (file >> word) {
            ++words[word];
        }
    }

    return (int)words.size();
}
```